# How to get only one device event using from powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using the below mentioned code to get usb device detection. But i am getting three device detection instead of one.

```
Register-WMIEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent 
    WITHIN 1 WHERE EventType = 2" -Action { Write-Host "Device detected"}
```

unexpected output
[image]

I want to get single detection when i insert usb.

Kindly guide me..

Comment: Check if your USB device represents a single entity in device manager AND does not have a subfunction detected as a separate instance of a something. Also sometimes (WinXP had this behavior with some Flash drives) a device was first detected, then disconnected, then connected again to get initialized properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand your question right your search something like that:

```
#Get all USB Device(This is your query)
$Devices = Register-WMIEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE EventType = 2"
#Check if the devices variable empty or not
if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Devices)){
    #Will be printed when one or more usb devices are connected
    Write-Host "Device detected"
}
```